# ¿Como puedo excluir y obtener un objeto de un array en javascript?

Tags: javascript, nodejs

tengo el siguiente código:

```
const options = [
  { id: '1', title: 'Por transacción', name: 'Por transacción' },
  { id: '2', title: 'Diario', name: 'Diario' },
  { id: '3', title: 'Mensual', name: 'Mensual' }
]

const selected = [
  { type_limit: '2' },
  { type_limit: '1' },
]
```

Necesito obtener el objeto de `options` que no este contenido dentro de `selected`

ejemplo de respuesta para este caso:

```
{ id: '3', title: 'Mensual', name: 'Mensual' }
```

Ahora si yo tengo en mi array `selected` solo un objeto con un id, me tendría que devolver la exclusión de los otros objetos y así dinámicamente.

Lo que he intentado es lo siguiente:

```
options.filter((el) => {
  return selected.some((item) => {
    return item.type_limit !== el.id
  })
})

// returns
// [
//   { id: '1', title: 'Por transacción', name: 'Por transacción' },
//   { id: '2', title: 'Diario', name: 'Diario' },
//   { id: '3', title: 'Mensual', name: 'Mensual' }
// ]
```

pero me da como respuesta todo el array de `options`

¿Alguien tiene una idea de como puedo solucionarlo?

Answer (score 0):

Hay forma simplificada de hacerlo; pero me explayare un poco.

Como quieres esos elementos de `selected`  que no están en `options` te sugiero primero pasar a un array los `id` de `options`

```js
const options = [
  { id: '1', title: 'Por transacción', name: 'Por transacción' },
  { id: '2', title: 'Diario', name: 'Diario' },
  { id: '3', title: 'Mensual', name: 'Mensual' }
]

const selected = [
  { type_limit: '2' },
  { type_limit: '1' },
]

// Obtenemos todos los ID
let losIds =selected.map(a => a.type_limit);
console.log("Los IDs", losIds);

// Buscamos cuales no estan
let NoExisten =options.filter((el) => {
  return losIds.indexOf(el.id)===-1;
});

console.log("Los que no esta", NoExisten);
```

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente encontré una forma de hacerlo, al array de `options` le aplico un filtro para poder realizar mis comparaciones:

```
options.filter((el) => {
  if (selected.find((filter) => filter.type_limit === el.id)) { } else {
    return el
  }
})
```

dentro del filtro realizo una condición para obtener mis objetos iguales, en `selected` y `options`. Ahora para obtener la exclusión simplemente le aplico un `! Not equal operator` para indicar que no necesito lo objetos iguales dentro de las 2 matrices.